# Is there an alternative to LiveBindings in FMX so I can use datasets generated by a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, livebindings

Right now my FMX project is totally based on Livebinding to connect the datasources to my editors on the form.

It works nice, besides to be slow and do not use paging loading (TLisView).

However, I have many different datasources and the amount of data can be huge and connections eventually slow.

My idea is to keep the user interface responsive and let threads in the background make the data load opening the datasources and put them it the right state. After that assigning the datasource to the controls on the form.

I have played with that with LiveBinding but I cannot mix the main thread with background ones. Some problems happened.

Having to load each field record to each control manually seems to be extremely unproductive. I have almost all the controls that I use already wrapped, I made my own controls based on the FMX ones, so I can have the possibility to add more functions.

I was wondering if there is something already done. Any class or library that I could use to map the source and targets and that I can have the control to activate when it is needed, since I can have many datasources in loading state by a thread.

Comment: I've tried building something like that and it's rather challenging. You need to rely on RTTI metadata and generics to build a map, and doing it inside of the IDE is also problematic. (I spent some time trying to figure out how they do it in the LiveBindings Wizard, and it's not at all obvious.) This was part of the context around which I based my CodeRage 9 presentation entitled "Have You Embraced Your Inner Plumber Lately?", although I wasn't able to delve into this topic in any detail. Maybe next time. My conclusion: the current shortcomings in Delphi's RTTI and generics make it very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a livebinding question.

Also without livebindings, when you retrieve data in a thread you have to respect the thread context. When getting a dataset from a connection, this dataset is also bound to that connection and the connection is bound to the thread context.

The solution is to copy the dataset into a clientdataset and hand over that CDS to the UI thread. Now you can bind that CDS wherever you like. Remember, that there is no connection between the CDS and the data connection. You have to take care yourself writing back the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is relevant still. I use livebinding frequently with load time for the underlying data using treads, utilizing the TTask.Run and Thread.Queue. The important point is to have the LiveBinding AutoActivate = FALSE (i.e. TLinkGridToDataBindSource or other livebinding).

Request is done in TThread.Run with Execute of query, and LiveBinding property "Active" set to True in a TThread.Queue [inside the TThread.Run]. The Livebinding is updating UI and must occur in the main thread.

Subsequent update/request is done the same way, setting active to false first.